# How to update a table column with a Sub query using a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables TableA, TableB and TableC. TableA has the following columns

```
    MyId
    IsFound
```

I want to update Table.IsFound to Yes or No based on the below result.

```
SELECT t1.MyId FROM  TableA t1 WHERE t1.MyId IN (
SELECT     t2.Id FROM
 TableB t2, TableC t3
 WHERE t2.Value1 = t3.Value1 AND t2.Value1 !='XXXX' AND  t3.Value1 !='XXXX');
```

Expected logic:

```
If t1.MyId is not null
  Update TableA.IsFound ="Yes"
Else
  Update TableA.IsFound ="No"
End If
```

Thanks for your help. I couldn't find the solution because of my basic SQL knowledge.

Comment: What you have currently is not a proper subquery. `UPDATE` requires you to select a table, column, and value to set it to. This is no exception in a subquery. Also note that double quotes make the engine look for a column with that name rather than taking the literal value. It should look more like `UPDATE TableA SET IsFound = 'Yes'`.

Comment: I want to incoprate Update statement with my sql

Comment: And I just told you how to.

Comment: Thanks, I got it and found the solution

Comment: @Jesse , _" double quotes make the engine look for a column with that name rather than taking the literal value"_ ? This is not true in MySQL [refer this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2500eb136dd06d11a019436d8fcfc12a)